# DIV's are getting pushed out window by other DIV's

Tags: css, html, height, css-position

I have this fairly unusual problem (after what I've understood when asking others), it seems that my -tags don't understand how much of the screen that is used by other elements, and therefore push elements out of screen.
I thought it might had something to do with the use of position:fixed, but it didn't seem to solve it when removing the position-part at all.

This is the main markup that seems to have problems, in wich I really can't seem to see any errors.

```
<div id="search">
    <div id="searchfield">
        <span id="searchinput">
            <input type="text" id="s" name="s" />
        </span>
        <button>Search</button>
    </div>
    <div id="searchresults">
        <ul class="longlist">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is best seen in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KX9BV/3/) where it seems *#searchresults* is pushed out of *#search* by *#searchfield*.
As I really don't know what's the problem, any attempt on using Google have left me with no good answer to where my problem really is.

I have tried removing any JS that modifies the at all, and as we can see the jsFiddle does not run any JS at all, and still my markup/CSS does not work.

The height of *#search* is set to 400px in this fiddle to show the flaw better. But the same error occurs when it's 100% (wich is the value it should have in production-code).

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an overflow problem. The div "#searchfield" is pushing down the other content.

Setting the height to "auto" by removing the line "height: 400px;" on "div#search" and set a fixed height on "div#searchresults" fixes the problem.

```
#search{
   height: 400px;
}
```

Taking the "div#searchfield" outside of the "div#search" also works.

```
<div id="searchfield">...</div>
<div id="search">...</div>
```

These methods show that the overflow problem is caused by mixing relative and absolute heights. You should move some of your styles relating to height from "div#search" into "div#searchresults" to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, moving the height property from *div#search* to *div#searchresults* seems to fix it when I use static heights.  But I really want to make it dynamic and use percentage to make *div#searchresults* fill the rest of the screen downwards beneath *div#searchfield*.
Or would it be a better solution to use JS to set *div#searchresults* height?

Comment: @JoMs One idea would be to wrap everything inside anoter div (with a height of 100%).

Comment: I believe I already did this with *div#content*, or do you think of another place in the code?

Comment: @JoMs Sorry, I mean't just arround the Search Form. See [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff5eu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work at

```
 #search{
   height: 100%;
 }
```

no?

link:

http://jsfiddle.net/KX9BV/8/

Comment: As you can see, the scrollbar actually appears to go outside the window.
With this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KX9BV/9/) one can see that when scrolling to bottom, both Foo 19 and Foo 20 is still outside of the screen.

Comment: In that case, as Hello Invader said, setting the #search div's height to auto and a fixed height to #searchresults fixes your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/KX9BV/19/